# What hypothesis test can test for *equivalent* variance, rather than different variance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, equivalence

There exist many "variance equality tests", like the [F-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances) and its more robust cousins: [Levene's, Bartlett's, the Brown-Forsythe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances#Properties).

Given two samples A and B with variances $\sigma_A^2$ and $\sigma_B^2$, one can use them to evaluate the null and alternate hypotheses:

- H0) $\sigma_A^2 = \sigma_B^2$
- H1) $\sigma_A^2 \neq \sigma_B^2$

Specifically, a sufficiently small $p$ allows us to reject the null hypothesis.  But a large $p$ just fails to reject the null.  **A large $p$ does NOT say the variances are equal.  The test is inconclusive.**

I am looking for a test which *can* say the variances are equal.  One which constructs the hypotheses with some small $\Delta$ as

- H0)

  $\sigma_A^2 - \sigma_B^2 \le -\Delta$

  or

  $\sigma_A^2 - \sigma_B^2 \ge \Delta$
- H1)

  $-\Delta \lt \sigma_A^2 - \sigma_B^2 \lt \Delta$

and allows rejection of the non-equivalence H0 with a sufficiently small $p$.

I think I am asking for something very similar to [TOST](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/545115/89612) or [Campbell and Ladkens Sec 4](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.11875), but for distribution variances instead of means.  Those are conveniently implemented in R packages [here](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/TOSTER/html/dataTOSTtwo.html) and [here](https://aaroncaldwell.us/TOSTERpkg/reference/equ_anova.html), resp.

I figured my problem would be commonplace enough that I could find a similar, single R call.  But no luck so far.  Help is *very* appreciated.

Comment: Isn’t this exactly what TOST does? The typical examples are for means, sure, but nothing about TOST is specific about means.

Comment: With variance it would make more sense to try to test whether the ratio was close to 1 than the difference close to 0, but (given that) you'd still seek to construct two one-sided tests.

Comment: @Dave The more I look, yes I think you're right.

Comment: With @Glen_b's point taken, [this tutorial](https://www.ncss.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Equivalence_Tests_for_the_Ratio_of_Two_Variances.pdf) lays out the process pretty much exactly.

Comment: I suspect that a reason for this not being commonplace is that if $\Delta$ is small relative to $\sigma^2_A$ and $\sigma^2_B$ then the sample size to get a non-zero probability  of rejecting the both the two null hypotheses becomes so big  that it is usually not useful.  Meanwhile a large $\Delta$ is hardly persuasive of equality.  Your link suggests that even aiming for a ratio neither below $\frac23$ nor above $\frac32$, to get a power of $0.9$ when there is precise equality you need a sample size of $532$ ($266$ on each distribution).  It would be bigger with a more plausible interval.

Comment: @Henry Very interesting and useful point!  (Luckily, I'm working in the samples sizes of thousands to tens of thousands.)

Comment: Speaking about TOST for mean equivalence for a second: Is the method from Campbell and Ladkens Sec 4 considered a TOST method??  I _think_ so, because it just sets a TOST-style confidence interval around ANOVA effect size $\eta^2$, rather than around the mean directly...

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the usual test under an assumption of normality will still tend to have the same [sensitivity to non-normality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances#Properties)  (in particular, sensitivity to the situation where kurtosis is different from that of the normal) as you have when testing equality of variance.

Comment: @Glen_b Of course!  Hence my mentioning a few variance tests that are robust to non-normality.